# Getting speed limit based on a single coordinate using here REST API

Tags: rest, routes, here-api, here-maps-rest

I want to retrieve speed limit based on a single coordinate(of a road in the USA) using HERE REST API(not PDE). So, I only got the api_key(no app code). I searched and found some solutions which were deprecated and required the PDE api. If anybody knows the latest solution please let me know. Thanks. Anyway I got something which gives speed limit for two coordinates(not my case) and if I put the two coordinates same I get the wrong(very small) value for speed limit. which is given bellow:

> https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey=APP_KEY&transportMode=car&origin=-37.956650,145.220673&destination=-37.956650,145.220673&spans=speedLimit&return=polyline

```
{
"routes": [
    {
        "id": "0a903f38-aecd-4850-a87e-0848c7583b8a",
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": "4aa23cb0-0209-4e31-bca8-32f4cfb9f98e",
                "type": "vehicle",
                "departure": {
                    "time": "2021-02-25T12:52:34+11:00",
                    "place": {
                        "type": "place",
                        "location": {
                            "lat": -37.9566675,
                            "lng": 145.2206532
                        },
                        "originalLocation": {
                            "lat": -37.9566501,
                            "lng": 145.220673
                        }
                    }
                },
                "arrival": {
                    "time": "2021-02-25T12:52:34+11:00",
                    "place": {
                        "type": "place",
                        "location": {
                            "lat": -37.9566675,
                            "lng": 145.2206532
                        },
                        "originalLocation": {
                            "lat": -37.9566501,
                            "lng": 145.220673
                        }
                    }
                },
                "polyline": "BG1j2soC6iy_0IAA",
                "spans": [
                    {
                        "offset": 0,
                        "speedLimit": 27.7777786
                    }
                ],
                "transport": {
                    "mode": "car"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Is there any latest rest api service provided by Here that gives speed limit for a geo coordinate(not the pde one)?

Comment: Hi Robin, you are right. Route V8 is one of the latest HERE location services that can get the speed limit. 
Based on your interests, you can also check HERE Fleet Telematics API.https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/use-cases.html
For the data concern(spped limit right or not),we believe it's right. If you do see any data problem please connect to HERE support team so we will follow up.

Comment: Thanks for commenting but could you share the api url that contains speed limit in the response please.